# How to fix AssertionError 200!=302

Tags: django, unit-testing, python-unittest

I got a registration view that registers new users, logs them in and then redirects them to home page. When I am testing this view using unittest I am getting an AssertionError 200!=302

views.py :

```
def register(request):

    if request.method =='POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
          user=form.save()
          username = request.POST.get('username')
          password = request.POST.get('password1')

          login(request, user)
          return redirect(reverse('home:home'))
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
    args = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/reg_form.html', args)
```

test_views.py:

```
class TestViews(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        self.burial=User.objects.create_user(
            username='burial',
            password='secret'
            )


    def test_registration_view(self):

        url = reverse('accounts:register')
        response = self.client.post(url, {
                'username': self.burial.username,
                'password': self.burial.password

                })

        self.client.login(username=self.burial.username, 
password=self.burial.password)
        self.assertEquals(self.burial.username, 'burial')
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 302)
```

I am getting AssertionError 200!=302

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Why are you trying to "register" already created (registered) user?

Comment: @IvanStarostin Sorry I am new to this, I just realised what I have done. In this case I would guess we use AnonymousUser? Thanks for your help btw.